# SQL Server - ESPG:4326 data stored in Geometry column

Tags: sql-server, latitude-longitude, srid, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

It seems that the Microsoft SQL Server [Geography](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017) data type is better suited for lat/lon because Geography *"stores ellipsoidal (round-earth) data, such as GPS latitude and longitude coordinates."*

While the [Geometry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data type *"represents data in a Euclidean (flat) coordinate system."*

I have data stored in SQL Server Geometry data type column, and it is lat/lon coordinates - the SRID is [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326).

The reason being, is the data is used by Geoserver, and Geoserver only recognizes Geometry data types for SQL Server. But the data is 4326.

Is there anything wrong with doing this?  Will there be accuracy or performance issue?  Should/could the data be converted?

Comment: what do you do with the data? is it a global coverage or regional?

Comment: Also I believe GeoServer can read the Geography column from an SQLServer DB at least from a quick look at the code base.

Comment: @IanTurton - mostly regional